# Django date effective retrieval of ORM records

Tags: django

If I have a Django `Employee` model with a `start_date` and `end_date` date field, how can I use get in the ORM to date effectively select the correct record if different versions of the record exist over time based on these date fields?

So I could have the following records:

```
start_date, end_date,   emp
01/01/2013, 31/01/2013, Emp1
01/02/2013, 28/02/2013, Employee1
01/03/2013, 31/12/4000. EmpOne
```

And if today's date is `10/02/2013` then I would want `Employee1`.

Something similar to:

```
from django.utils import timezone
current_year = timezone.now().year
Employee.objects.get(end_date__year=current_year)
```

or

```
res = Employee.objects.filter(end_date__gt=datetime.now()).order_by('-start_date')
```

Or is there a more efficient way of doing the same?

Comment: What if there are more than one rows that match the current date?

Comment: There is only one date effective version of a record.

Comment: Are you searching for the closest end_date compared to the current time?

Comment: No, I'm searching for the record where the end_date is greater than or equal to today's date and the start_date is less than or equal to today's date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second example looks fine. I corrected the filter parameters to match your start_date constraints. Also, i added a `LIMIT 1` (`[:1]`) for better performance:

```
now = datetime.now()
employees = Employee.objects.filter(start_date__lt=now, end_date__gt=now).order_by('-start_date')
employee = employees[:1][0] if employees else None
```